# Changing favicon for admin side theme only - Magento 2.3

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, adminhtml, custom-theme

I've made the custom adminhtml theme and changed the login logo and the default top left logo on dashboard, however I'm unable to change the admin favicon.

In the default.xml that I'm using to modify the header logo i have added

```
<head>
    <link src="images/favicon.ico" rel="icon" sizes="32x32" />
</head>
```

to call a custom favicon that is stored in the app/design/adminhtml/**%vendor%/%theme%**/web/images/ folder but even though the logos have loaded fine, the favicon remains the same as the front-end.

is there a different string i should be using in the ? i have taken this string directly from the frontend favicon tutorial, so don't know what it would need changing for the adminhtml sections

I have also tested this in the **default_head_blocks.xml** but that appears to be front-end specific.

**Edit:**

It appears that the theme is active, (can change .phtml files successfully) but the default.xml and the admin_login.xml are both being ignored anyway. if i remove those files, the logo files with the default names load fine, but with the files in place the newly linked files from the xmls are ignored.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, If you've set favicon from Design Config, you need to remove that icon if you want to display different favicon for front-end and back-end.

So please remove favicon icon from here and save config and then clear cache.

> Content > Design > Configuration > Select your Store view and edit > HTML Head > Favicon icon > Remove > Save Config

And if there is not any favicon set then you can copy your `favicon.ico` from here

> pub/media/favicon/stores//favicon.ico

and move that to your frontend theme first here..

> app/design/frontend/Vendor/Theme/Magento_Theme/web/favicon.ico

Then after you can use below steps for Backend theme favicon icon.

You can add your favicon.ico image here in your adminhtml theme

> app/design/adminhtml/Vendor/Theme/Magento_Theme/web/favicon.ico

Because in default Magento Backend theme that icon available here.

> vendor/magento/module-theme/view/adminhtml/web/favicon.ico

If you will add that icon with same name **favicon.ico** then that will work for you. Then you do not need to make any changes in any other xml files.

Please run below command once

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento cache:clean
php bin/magento cache:flush
```

Hope this will work for you!

Comment: Can you please check in your **pub/static/adminhtml/Vendor/Theme/Magento_Theme/web/** directory ?

If there is old favicon.ico available can you please remove that and then refresh your page ?

Comment: Is above solution works for you ?

Comment: there is nothing in that folder, but all of the images on the backend are in a static/version*******/adminhtml folder which won't be cleared.

Comment: Can you please place your favicon.ico on above mentioned path? And check result in browser's private window once?

Comment: Otherwise please do inspect element and check from where that image is coming?

Comment: Are you able to find solution or above solution was helpful to you ?

Comment: manually changing the favicon.ico on that path did not work

Comment: can you please remove adminhtml directory from you pub/static and then check once ?

Comment: Run this commands..

rm -rf pub/static/*

Comment: i have run that command several times, but the problem is that the favicon is still being pulled from pub/media/favicon/default/ rather than any adminhtml theme

Comment: Can you please confirm you've created Backend theme properly ? https://github.com/KishanSavaliya/magehelper-magento2-overrite-backend-theme

Comment: And try to update copyright text in backend first. So you'll get idea if that is the issue or anything other is there.

Comment: I have made the theme correctly and as i've said the logos are updating fine, and are pulling from the static/adminhtml/XXXXX/backend/en_US folders fine, just not the favicon.

in setup:static-content:deploy it deploys the backend themes correctly,

Comment: i have also now tested the change to the copyright text, works fine

Comment: Okay, I'll update you tomorrow. I also noticed that in my Magento 2.1.6 setup favicon icon coming from pub media directory.

Comment: I've updated my answer that will definitely works for you. I've also tested that at my end twice.

Comment: removing the frontend favicon immediately makes the backend one work, which is very promising.

Comment: If icon is available on pub/media directory then Magento will take that first for both front-end and back-end. So if we need both icon separate then we need to follow above way.

Comment: Approve my answer if above solution helpful to you! Thanks in advance. :)